# Drop Down Animate Contact Box

Tags: javascript, animation, popup, contacts

I have been looking all day for a way to make a contact form similar to the one on this site: http://45royale.com/ 
If you click on the contact button a black background fades in and the from drops down using an ease function. I have been picking through the code trying to see what to do but I am stuck and I have also been looking and other javascript pop ups but so far it seems they only use php for the form however this one calls a html.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something like the form in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/ep39v/3/.
And the source:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form"></div>
<button id="showFormBtn">Show form</button>
​
```

**JavaScript**

```
var form = $('.form');

$('#showFormBtn').click(function () {
    fadeBackground(showForm);
});

(function () {
    form.css({
        top: -form.height(),
        left: ($(document.body).width() - form.width()) / 2
    });
}());

function fadeBackground(callback) {
    var background = $('<div class="background"></div>');
    $(document.body).append(background);
    background.fadeTo(300, 0.5, function () {
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback();
        }
    });        
}

function showForm() {
   var form = $('.form');
    form.animate({ top: 10 }, 1500, 'easeOutElastic');
}
​
```

**CSS**

```
.form {
    width: 30%;
    height: 40%;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.background {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
}​
```

May be you need to change only the [easing](http://jqueryui.com/effect/).

Comment: Awesome stuff it really gives me a good place to start with thank you! I just made one tiny change and I put a z-index on the form so I could have it as white and appearing on top of the background besides that its perfect! One more question though where should I look for a good script so I can either click on a close button or outside the form?

Comment: Here you can close the form by clicking the background http://jsfiddle.net/ep39v/12/

Comment: Again, fantastic stuff! This will help me loads!

Comment: Ok new problem, I have finished my testing in jsfiddle but I can't get it to work in dreamweaver, I have attached the jquery-ui.min.js file and a file with the javascript in it but its not working, any idea why?

Comment: No idea. I'm not using dreameaver, I prefer vim.

Comment: It's a text editor. I don't like heavy IDE like Dreamweaver/Visual Studio/Eclipse and so on... :-)